# Why is apache redirecting to one of ServerAlias?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using two top level domains `.pl` and `.net`. Both should always redirect to `https` version however when user go to `http://example.net/` apache redirects to `https://example.pl/`. Why it is preferable even when it is on third position in `ServerAlias`? Apache redirect to `.net` only if I remove `.pl` from `ServerAlias`.
My `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.pl.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example
   DocumentRoot /var/www/example.pl
   ServerAlias example.net www.example.net example.pl www.example.pl
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.pl

        <Directory "/var/www/example.pl">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ServerName example

        LogLevel trace8 rewrite:trace8
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/2_example.pl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/1_root_bundle.crt

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Looks like the rewrite is coming from backend, check Laravel settings

Comment: I am logging every rewrite and first rewrite already see example.pl.

Comment: well, then that first rewrite is coming from laravel, because it is not from .conf nor htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Why making it so complicated with .htaccess if you have access to the main conf?

Defining the virtulahosts should be enough like:

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80 <-- uncomment only with 2.2
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.net
Redirect / https://example.net/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.pl
Redirect / https://example.pl/
</VirtualHost>
```

Or if you are lazy and just want to define one virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bogus.example
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: .htaccess comes from PHP Laravel framework so I decided to not touch it.

Comment: I recommend you to strip the rewrite to https part in your .htaccess and try my suggestions, will make your life much easier imo.

Comment: First version (without touching .htaccess) works fine. However the lazy version still redirects to wrong domain.

Comment: I tested both (without your .htaccess) and they work for me. You could try chasing the responses with `curl -I http://example.net` or a web console and see if its the first redirection or some later rewrites. In any case... glad it worked for you.

Comment: Well derp, I just noticed that (event with stripped .htaccess) both versions periodically switches from
`curl -I example.net HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 18:30:45 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Location: https://example.net/ Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` to `curl -I example.net HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 18:26:25 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Location: https://example.pl/ Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: so sometimes, 302 (my suggestions), sometimes a 301 (something else)? Review your config deeply...